# How to read to a certain point in python for every line

Tags: python, function, variables, line

I tried to read from every line until the `,` so that I can edit it with format to add my text but I don't know which code to use to read until a certain point for every line. I tried to search on the web but I couldn't find anything

```
def pretty_print():
    file = open('kaartnummers', 'r')
    # print(file.read())
    print(file.read())

pretty_print()
```

Contents of `kaartnummer` text file

```
325255, Jan Jansen
334343, Erik Materus
235434, Ali Ahson
645345, Eva Versteeg
534545, Jan de Wilde
345355, Henk de Vries
```

Desired output:

```
Jan Jansen heeft kaartnummer: 325255
Erik Materus heeft kaartnummer: 334343
Ali Ahson heeft kaartnummer: 235434
Eva Versteeg heeft kaartnummer: 645345
Jan de Wilde heeft kaartnummer: 534545
Henk de Vrie heeft kaartnummer: 345355
```

Answer (score 2):

```
with open("sample.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in content_list:
        if "," in line:
            line_sepperated = line.split(",")
            name = line_sepperated[1]
            num = line_sepperated[0]
            print(f'{name} heeft kaartnummer: {num}')
        else:
            print(line)
```

short explanation:

- open and read the file, and split it to list of lines
- iterate over the lines: if `,` exist - split the line by it and print by formatting wanted, if not - print the whole line

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it.

the command that fixed it was

```
.replace("\n", "")
```

right now i have

```
print(f'{num} heeft kaartnummer: {name}'.replace("\n", ""))
print('{} heeft kaarnummer: {}'.format(*[num], *[name]).replace("\n", ""))
print(str(num).replace("\n", "")+' heeft kaartnummer: '+str(name).replace("\n", ""))
```

and it works on all the 3 print lines